# Grouping elements from arrays by index into List<Map<String,Object>>

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a Map<String, Object[]> in which key is the Array's name Object identifier aka collection name and its corresponding array of Objects.

The objective is to be able to Merge the different entries of the Object [] into a List<Map<String,Object>> where the keys of each Map corresponds to the known Collection name and the Object is the iTh value of each array.

In order to clarify this more:

Lets say we have a Map<String, Object[]> with the following arrays.

```
    Map<String, Object[]> map = new HasMap<>();

    Object[] ints = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5).toArray();
    Object[] dobules = Stream.of(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0).toArray();
    Object[] strings = Stream.of("a","b","c","d","e").toArray();

    map.put("ints", ints);
    map.put("doubles", dobules);
    map.put("strings", strings);
```

Then the output of this entry should be like this:

List<Map<String,Object>> where for the example up the List of maps would be like this

```
{"ints": 1, "doubles":1.0, "strings":"a"},
{"ints": 2, "doubles":2.0, "strings":"b"},
{"ints": 3, "doubles":3.0, "strings":"c"},
{"ints": 4, "doubles":4.0, "strings":"d"},
{"ints": 5, "doubles":5.0, "strings":"e"}
```

I am looking specially a solution using java Collection streams
Thank you so much

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's like a homework question. I'm sure an example of what they tried with streams and what isn't working would be more likely to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain old approach:

```java
List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();

if(!map.isEmpty()) 
    // Assume all the array lengths are the same
    int length = map.values().iterator().next().length;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Object[]> entry : map.entrySet()) {
           row.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()[i]; 
        }
        result.add(row);
    }
}
```

---

Mixed approach:

```java
int length = map.values().iterator().next().length;

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    final int index = i; // make compiler happy
    result.add(map.entrySet()
                  .stream()
                  .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue()[index])));
}
```

---

Pure functional approach:

```java
int length = map.isEmpty() ? 0 : map.values().iterator().next().length;

List<Map<String, Object>> result = 
    IntStream.range(0, length)
             .boxed()
             .map(i -> map.entrySet()
                          .stream()
                          .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue()[i])))
             .collect(toList());
```

Comment: You could use an `IntStream` instead of for-loop in your second example. Then you should also be able to collect everything into a `List`

Comment: @BenjaminM Right.

Comment: That was exactly what i was searching for. I thought i should use a flatmap but didn't found the correct way. Seems that using Instream is the way to go. Thank you so much!